# Pandas str.replace skipping some replacements

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a column `ms_sample_id` in a pandas dataframe named `selected_id_df`. The unique rows are given by

```
selected_id_df.ms_sample_id.unique()
```

Which yields:

```
   array(['mitra_baseline_310808-1', 'mitra_baseline_310808-2',
   'mitra_baseline_310808-3', 'mitra_baseline_310808-4',
   'mitra_baseline_310907-1', 'mitra_baseline_310907-2',
   'mitra_baseline_310907-3', 'mitra_baseline_310907-4',
   'mitra_baseline_311090-1', 'mitra_baseline_311090-2',
   'mitra_baseline_311090-3', 'mitra_baseline_311090-4',
   'mitra_baseline_311091-1', 'mitra_baseline_311091-2',
   'mitra_baseline_311091-3', 'mitra_baseline_311091-4',
   'mitra_baseline_311123-1', 'mitra_baseline_311123-2',
   'mitra_baseline_311123-3', 'mitra_baseline_311123-4',
   'frozen-2w_310808-1', 'frozen-2w_310808-2', 'frozen-2w_310907-1',
   'frozen-2w_310907-2', 'frozen-2w_311090-1', 'frozen-2w_311090-2',
   'frozen-2w_311091-1', 'frozen-2w_311091-2', 'frozen-2w_311123-1',
   'frozen-2w_311123-2', 'RT-2w_310808-1', 'RT-2w_310808-2',
   'RT-2w_310907-1', 'RT-2w_310907-2', 'RT-2w_311090-1',
   'RT-2w_311090-2', 'RT-2w_311091-1', 'RT-2w_311091-2',
   'RT-2w_311123-1', 'RT-2w_311123-2', 'LT_RT_310808_1',
   'LT_RT_310808_2', 'LT_RT_310907_1', 'LT_RT_310907_2',
   'LT_RT_311090_1', 'LT_RT_311090_2', 'LT_RT_311091_1',
   'LT_RT_311091_2', 'LT_RT_311123_1', 'LT_RT_311123_2',
   'LT-frozen_310808_1', 'LT-frozen_310808_2', 'LT-frozen_310907_1',
   'LT-frozen_310907_2', 'LT-frozen_311090_1', 'LT-frozen_311090_2',
   'LT-frozen_311091_1', 'LT-frozen_311091_2', 'LT-frozen_311123_1',
   'LT-frozen_311123_2'], dtype=object)
```

I would like to replace some of the `-` in the ids with `_`. I do this as follows:

```
selected_id_df.loc[:,'ms_sample_id'] = (selected_id_df.loc[:,'ms_sample_id'] 
                                   .str.strip()
                                   .str.replace("frozen_2w", 'frozen-2w')
                                   .str.replace("RT_2w", 'RT-2w')
                                   .str.replace('mitra_baseline', 'mitra-baseline')
                                   .str.replace('LT_RT', 'LT-RT')                                      
                                   .str.replace('-1', '_1')
                                   .str.replace('-2', '_2')
                                   .str.replace('-3', '_3')
                                   .str.replace('-4', '_4'))
```

After running the above statement, I again use

```
selected_id_df.ms_sample_id.unique()
```

Which this time yields:

```
array(['mitra-baseline_310808_1', 'mitra-baseline_310808_2',
   'mitra-baseline_310808_3', 'mitra-baseline_310808_4',
   'mitra-baseline_310907_1', 'mitra-baseline_310907_2',
   'mitra-baseline_310907_3', 'mitra-baseline_310907_4',
   'mitra-baseline_311090_1', 'mitra-baseline_311090_2',
   'mitra-baseline_311090_3', 'mitra-baseline_311090_4',
   'mitra-baseline_311091_1', 'mitra-baseline_311091_2',
   'mitra-baseline_311091_3', 'mitra-baseline_311091_4',
   'mitra-baseline_311123_1', 'mitra-baseline_311123_2',
   'mitra-baseline_311123_3', 'mitra-baseline_311123_4',
   'frozen_2w_310808_1', 'frozen_2w_310808_2', 'frozen_2w_310907_1',
   'frozen_2w_310907_2', 'frozen_2w_311090_1', 'frozen_2w_311090_2',
   'frozen_2w_311091_1', 'frozen_2w_311091_2', 'frozen_2w_311123_1',
   'frozen_2w_311123_2', 'RT_2w_310808_1', 'RT_2w_310808_2',
   'RT_2w_310907_1', 'RT_2w_310907_2', 'RT_2w_311090_1',
   'RT_2w_311090_2', 'RT_2w_311091_1', 'RT_2w_311091_2',
   'RT_2w_311123_1', 'RT_2w_311123_2', 'LT-RT_310808_1',
   'LT-RT_310808_2', 'LT-RT_310907_1', 'LT-RT_310907_2',
   'LT-RT_311090_1', 'LT-RT_311090_2', 'LT-RT_311091_1',
   'LT-RT_311091_2', 'LT-RT_311123_1', 'LT-RT_311123_2',
   'LT-frozen_310808_1', 'LT-frozen_310808_2', 'LT-frozen_310907_1',
   'LT-frozen_310907_2', 'LT-frozen_311090_1', 'LT-frozen_311090_2',
   'LT-frozen_311091_1', 'LT-frozen_311091_2', 'LT-frozen_311123_1',
   'LT-frozen_311123_2'], dtype=object)
```

​We can see that my replacement statement has not worked for 2 of my replacements:

```
.str.replace("frozen_2w", 'frozen-2w')
.str.replace("RT_2w", 'RT-2w')
```

I am incredibly puzzled, why is this happening?

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you provided right input and output? For example, in initial dataframe there's row with value `frozen-2w_310907-1` and after `replace("frozen_2w", 'frozen-2w')`, there's row with value `frozen_2w_310907_1`.

Comment: Do .str.replace('-2', '_2') before .str.replace("frozen_2w", 'frozen-2w')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex solution:

```
s.replace('-(?=[0-9])','_', regex=True).replace('_(?=2w|baseline|RT)','-', regex=True)
```

Explanation:

- We use regex to find `-` before a number `[0-9]` and replace with `_`
- We use regex again to find `_` before `2w or baseline or RT` and replace with `-`

Exemplified:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['mitra_baseline_310808-1', 'mitra_baseline_310808-2',
   'mitra_baseline_310808-3', 'mitra_baseline_310808-4',
   'mitra_baseline_310907-1', 'mitra_baseline_310907-2',
   'mitra_baseline_310907-3', 'mitra_baseline_310907-4',
   'mitra_baseline_311090-1', 'mitra_baseline_311090-2',
   'mitra_baseline_311090-3', 'mitra_baseline_311090-4',
   'mitra_baseline_311091-1', 'mitra_baseline_311091-2',
   'mitra_baseline_311091-3', 'mitra_baseline_311091-4',
   'mitra_baseline_311123-1', 'mitra_baseline_311123-2',
   'mitra_baseline_311123-3', 'mitra_baseline_311123-4',
   'frozen_2w_310808-1', 'frozen-2w_310808-2', 'frozen-2w_310907-1',
   'frozen-2w_310907-2', 'frozen-2w_311090-1', 'frozen-2w_311090-2',
   'frozen-2w_311091-1', 'frozen-2w_311091-2', 'frozen-2w_311123-1',
   'frozen-2w_311123-2', 'RT-2w_310808-1', 'RT-2w_310808-2',
   'RT-2w_310907-1', 'RT-2w_310907-2', 'RT-2w_311090-1',
   'RT-2w_311090-2', 'RT-2w_311091-1', 'RT-2w_311091-2',
   'RT-2w_311123-1', 'RT-2w_311123-2', 'LT_RT_310808_1',
   'LT_RT_310808_2', 'LT_RT_310907_1', 'LT_RT_310907_2',
   'LT_RT_311090_1', 'LT_RT_311090_2', 'LT_RT_311091_1',
   'LT_RT_311091_2', 'LT_RT_311123_1', 'LT_RT_311123_2',
   'LT-frozen_310808_1', 'LT-frozen_310808_2', 'LT-frozen_310907_1',
   'LT-frozen_310907_2', 'LT-frozen_311090_1', 'LT-frozen_311090_2',
   'LT-frozen_311091_1', 'LT-frozen_311091_2', 'LT-frozen_311123_1',
   'LT-frozen_311123_2'])

print(s.replace('-(?=[0-9])','_', regex=True).replace('_(?=2w|baseline|RT)','-', regex=True))
```